# How to handle data fetch in react/redux component with propTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

There is a component called Document that displays the details of a document.

Document.js

```
export class Document extends Component {

  componentDidMount () {
    if (this.props.documentId) {
      this.props.fetchDocument(this.props.documentId)
    }
  }


  render () {
    const {document} = this.props
    if (!document) {
      return <div>No document yet</div>
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Document {document.name}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Document.propTypes = {
  documentId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  document: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  fetchDocument: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}
```

The Document component is created using the redux connect() function in DocumentContainer.

DocumentContainer.js

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const {documentId} = ownProps.match.params
  const document = state.documents.items[documentId]
  return {
    documentId: documentId,
    document: document,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchDocument: (documentId) => {
      dispatch(fetchDocument(documentId))
    },
  }
}

const DocumentContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Document)

export default DocumentContainer
```

The main component called App routes to the DocumentContainer component.

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  render () {
      return (
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/document/:documentId" component={DocumentContainer}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(App))
```

The problem is that the Document component has document as a required propType. But the document only gets loaded (invoking the action fetchDocument) after the component did mount. So I get this warning:

> index.js:2177 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `document` is marked
>   as required in `Document`, but its value is `undefined`

Is there a best practice to solve this problem?

Solutions I considered:
 - Create another component called DocumentLoader and route to that component in App. The DocumentLoader then loads the document and only renders the Document component once the document has loaded. Has the disadvantage of needing to create another component.
 - Load the document in the mapStateToProps function of the App component using ownProps.match.params. This can get painful however when there are 10 other components that need to be loaded in the App component and I loose some of the simplicity of react-router-dom.

**I ended up doing the following:**
- Move fetchDocument from componentDidMount to componentWillMount in the component Document
- Add a `isLoading` to the state that gets set to `true` as soon as the fetching starts
- Add `document ? document : {},` to `mapStateToProps` in DocumentContainer
- Replace `if(!document)` with `if(isLoading)`

What I am still unsure about is if it is the best solution to fetch the data in the component itself or if there is a better approach. I did not find any resources explaining how to do this in any other way (eg. with a middleware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider one more thing here, put a check whether document is available or not in the container component itself, if it is not available, just return an empty object.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const {documentId} = ownProps.match.params
  const document = state.documents.items[documentId]
  return {
    documentId: documentId,
    document: document ? document : {},
  }
}
```

And you should also put a check for empty object in the Document component like this,

```
const {document} = this.props
if (Object.keys(document).length === 0) {
  return <div>No document yet</div>
}

return (
  <div>
    <h1>Document {document.name}</h1>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! This will surely make the warning get away. But I agree with Michal that I might have to change the place where I fetch the document.

Comment: Moving the fetch call to `componentWillMount` won't let you help in getting away with the warning you are getting, if you want to keep the prop required, you can also use _.get function from lodash library and you can totally avoid the null-checks in the container component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the fetch document logic to `componentWillMount` lifecycle.

```
componentWillMount () {
  if (this.props.documentId) {
    this.props.fetchDocument(this.props.documentId)
  }
}
```

Also usually you don't call `fetch` in your component. You want to use some kind of middleware. When you start fetching the document you set flag `isLoadingDocument` to `true` in your store. Then instead of doing the `if(!document)` you do something like `if(isLadingDocument)`.

Comment: This approach sounds solid to me. Thanks for the hint!
Are there some tutorials/docs I should read to understand how to use a middleware in this case?

Comment: Moving the fetch call from `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount` will not prevent the warning you receive in the question. You are fetching slightly sooner but the time it takes to fetch may be longer than the time it takes to render, throwing the warning that I thought you wanted to avoid.

Comment: Yes Travis, you are right about that. That will not avoid the warning. But using a middleware to make the fetch and setting `isLoadingDocument` in the store sounds very reasonable.

Comment: Some people actually don't like storing the information about UI in global store. However, right now it is a common way to do things. I believe that you can find nice example here: https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Answer (score 0):

You already handle the situation where document isn't defined in your render function:

```
if (!document) {
  return <div>No document yet</div>
}
```

So you could remove the `isRequired` from `document: PropTypes.object.isRequired,` which becomes `document: PropTypes.object,`.

This will possibly throw a linting error as you don't require `document` but no `defaultProp` defined for it. To fix that, you can specify the defaultProps:

```
Document.defaultProps = {
  document: undefined,
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer! This will surely make the warning get away. But I agree with Michal that I might have to change the place where I fetch the document.